# How to target the first img in multiple divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the first `img` in this HTML structure with pseudo elements.

```
<div class="blog">
  <div
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so many combinations, but nothing. This is probably the best combination I have so far, but it only works if the `img` is the second div in the .blog. The first `img` needs to be targeted regardless of position.

```
.blog > div:nth-of-type(2) > .image > a > img
```

Comment: You need Javascript. Css can only look for/select next sibbling or children. Your element is nested, therefor you cannot access parents, nor sibbling parent's via CSS selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relay on jQuery to make this easy to handle: [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function

once parent are found add them a class [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Create that class in your style sheet.

Now you might have sibblings with similar class.

You can reset to whatever you want every sibblings coming next the first one with the **`~`** selector

```js
$(".blog > div").has(".image").addClass(" seenAtFirst");
```

```css
/* set regular and reset next similar targets */
.blog>div,
.seenAtFirst ~ .seenAtFirst  {
  border:none;
  background:turquoise;
  color:black;
  text-align:initial;/* initial can also be used to reset style */
}
/* set my first target*/
div.seenAtFirst {
  border:solid green;
  color:white;
  background:tomato;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog">
  <div>
    <h3>title</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="no-image">
      <a>
        <img>no-img
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>Target me and reset also next ones if any.
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>img
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>img
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>img
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, @GCyrillus! While I didn't use your code exactly, I took parts from it and was able to develop a solution.

Comment: @Weebs great, it does mean the answer was usefull and helped you to learn something ;)

Comment: Definitely! I would not have been able to develop the solution without your input. Thank you again! =]

Answer (score 0):

Well the most simple way I can think of is to give it an id, so you can track it by it's id, like this:

```css
img#first_img {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="blog">
  <div
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img id="first_img">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <a>
        <img>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```